# Python networkx diagram label printing question

Tags: python, networkx

I just started using networkx to construct and draw diagrams that display Nodes and edges between the node. I can this part to work without any issues.
My issue to do with how the label for the edges is printed.
I have the following code that creates a simple three-node topology with three edges.

```
node_def = ["N1", "N2", "N3",]

nodes = []

edgelist = [("N1", "N2"), 
            ("N1", "N3"), 
            ("N2", "N3"),
           ]

link_count = {}

G = nx.Graph()
G = nx.Graph(edgelist)

for node in G.nodes():
    nodes.append(node)

for node in G.nodes():
    link_count[node]=list()


#Figure out number of links/edges per node
for edge in G.edges():
    for node in edge:
        #print(node)
        tmp = len(link_count[node])
        link_count[node].insert(tmp, tmp+1)
    
print(link_count)

labels = {}

for edge in G.edges():
    labels[edge] = f"{link_count[edge[0]].pop(0)} | {link_count[edge[1]].pop(0)}"

print(labels)
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)  # calculate node positions
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels=labels, label_pos=0.5)
plt.show()
```

You will see that my edge labels are created from the above code as follows:

`{('N1', 'N2'): '1 | 1', ('N1', 'N3'): '2 | 1', ('N2', 'N3'): '2 | 2'}`

Interpretation of the above label edges is as follows:
link ID 1 on N1 connects to link ID 1 on N2 ('1 | 1')
link ID 2 on N1 connects to link ID 1 on N3 ('2 | 1')
and so forth....

With the link IDs ordered above, I want the edge labels to be printed in the same way on the diagram. See below, but this is not the case.

When I draw this topology this is when I have a problem.
You see in the picture below I am using the labels to also represent the link ID on each node.
In the picture N1 can only have a unique ID starting on it, the edge label between N3 and N1 should be printed as "1 | 2", where 2 is facing the N1 side. I cannot have same link ID starting on the same node.
I do not know if there is way to have this level of control when printing the labels.
Ideally, I would like to print each label for each node close to each node and have control for label per link per node. But it looks like you can only have a label per edge and then you can control how this is printed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think fixing the positions of the nodes may work if the no.of nodes is small.

Here is the edited code:

```
node_def = ["N1", "N2", "N3",]
edgelist = [("N1", "N2"), 
            ("N1", "N3"), 
            ("N2", "N3"),]

nodes = []
link_count = {}

G = nx.Graph(edgelist)

for node in G.nodes():
    nodes.append(node)
    link_count[node]=list()

# Figure out number of links/edges per node
for edge in G.edges():
    for node in edge:
        tmp = len(link_count[node])
        link_count[node].insert(tmp, tmp+1)
    
print(link_count)

labels = {}
for edge in G.edges():
    labels[edge] = f"{link_count[edge[0]].pop(0)} | {link_count[edge[1]].pop(0)}"
print(labels)

# Changed here
fixed_pos = {"N1":(1,1), "N3":(2,2), "N2":(3,1)}
pos = nx.spring_layout(G, pos=fixed_pos)  # calculate node positions
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels=labels, label_pos=0.5)
plt.show()
```

The only part I have really changed is

```
# Changed here
fixed_pos = {"N1":(1,1), "N3":(2,2), "N2":(3,1)}
pos = nx.spring_layout(G, pos=fixed_pos)  # calculate node positions
```

In the dictionary, the node is the key and its position in XY-Axes is the value.